# Dynamic templatetag

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have my own templatetag:

```
@register.inclusion_tag('path_to_module.html', takes_context=True)
def getmodule(context, token):
    try:
        return slow_function(params)
    except Exception, e:
        return None
```

And it is very slow. Template waiting for this tags.

Can I call them asynchonously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's cacheable (doesn't need to be unique per page view); then cache it. Either using [Django's cache API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#the-low-level-cache-api) in your templatetag, or [template fragment caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/?from=olddocs#template-fragment-caching) directly in your template. As @jpic says, if it's something that takes a while to recalculate - pass it off to a task queue like Celery.

If you need this function to run every page view for whatever reason; then separate it out in to a new view and load it in to some container in your main template asynchronously using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute python functions in a background process:

- [django-ztask](https://github.com/dmgctrl/django-ztask)
- [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) ([django kombu](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-kombu) for database transport)
- [uWSGI spooler](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/wiki/Spooler) (if using uWSGI for deployment)

You could create a background task that renders path_to_module and caches the output. When the cache should be invalidated: run slow_function in the background again.